# YOLOP pretrained model

Tags: python, deep-learning, object-detection, yolov5, pre-trained-model

I am using the pretrained YOLOP model to create a road lane detector so far I managed to run the model. However I am un able to understand how I can view the output of the model and how can I plot the detected items? How to access the loss and confidence values ?
I believe that da_seg_out is the detected road ll_sed_out is the detected lane.

Please help.

```
import torch

# load model
model = torch.hub.load('hustvl/yolop', 'yolop', pretrained=True)

#Load Image
path="drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Road/Road/solidWhiteCurve.jpg"
img = mpimg.imread(path)

#Resize image and convert to tesor
t = transforms.ToTensor()
resize_transform=transforms.Resize((640,640))
tensor_to_image=transforms.ToPILImage()
features=t(img)
features=resize_transform(features)

#inference
det_out, da_seg_out,ll_seg_out = model(features)
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have successfully loaded the YOLOP model and processed an image. To view the output of the model, you can use the det_out variable, which contains the detected objects and their corresponding bounding boxes.

The det_out variable is a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary contains information about a detected object. The information includes the class label, confidence score, and the bounding box coordinates.

To plot the detected items, you can use a library like matplotlib. Here's an example code snippet that can help you visualize the detected objects:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# plot original image
plt.imshow(img)

# plot detected objects
for det in det_out:
    label, confidence, bbox = det['label'], det['confidence'], det['bbox']
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = bbox
    plt.gca().add_patch(plt.Rectangle((x1, y1), x2-x1, y2-y1, fill=False, edgecolor='red', linewidth=2))
    plt.text(x1, y1-3, f"{label} ({confidence:.2f})", color='red')

# show plot
plt.show()
```

This code will plot the original image and draw bounding boxes around the detected objects, with the corresponding class labels and confidence scores. You may need to adjust the line thickness or color of the bounding boxes to better suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but running this codes gives me error
`
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-0d919126e1bf> in <cell line: 7>()
      6 # plot detected objects
      7 for det in det_out:
----> 8     label, confidence, bbox = det['label'], det['confidence'], det['bbox']
      9     x1, y1, x2, y2 = bbox
     10     plt.gca().add_patch(plt.Rectangle((x1, y1), x2-x1, y2-y1, fill=False, edgecolor='red', linewidth=2))
TypeError: new(): invalid data type 'str''

`

Comment: It seems that the `det_out` variable contains data in the form of numpy arrays rather than dictionaries. Could you please add `print(det)` inside the for loop before the line `label, confidence, bbox = det['label'], det['confidence'], det['bbox']`

Comment: was this answer written with AI assistance?